# What is the correctly way to publish message to saga using kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, saga

I'm designing a library using the cqrs pattern. I treat saga as an aggregate using the method mentioned in https://blog.jonathanoliver.com/cqrs-sagas-with-event-sourcing-part-i-of-ii/.

Here I have question on how to implement the message delivery that subscribed by a saga.

Let's say I have two aggregates, Account and MoneyTransferSaga in the application.
TransferMoney command would trigger the MoneySent event that reduce the amount of account balance.
MoneySent event would trigger the creation of MoneyTransferSaga which dispatch the ReceiveMoney command to another Account that would increase the amount of account balance.

So, we can see MoneyTransferSaga is subscribing the event MoneySent. The question I would like to ask is, what is the correct way to send this MoneySent event to the saga?

I'm using kafka as the message broker and here I have topics account-commands and account-events for the account aggregate.

Approach A: mark the MoneyTransferSaga as another consumer group which subscribe the topic "account-events". When the coming event match the type "MoneySent", trigger the saga event handler. Other events would be ignored by the saga event handler.

Approach B: create a topic called "money-transfer-saga-events". When event is sent to account-events, the account event handler duplicate the event to topic "money-transfer-saga-events". The MoneyTransferSaga subscribe the topic "money-transfer-saga-events" instead of "account-events".

I'm not sure which approach is better.

Using approach A, the saga instance would receive the all the events from account.

Using approach B, the account service have to know the existence of MoneyTransferSaga.

Thanks.